# Objective C: How to get navigation controller from ViewController behind my current ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, hierarchy

I have ViewController 1 with navigation controller where I'd like to push some other VC. But I have ViewController 2 presented over it not in navigation controller hierarchy.

In ViewController 2 I have some methods to minimise it, but I can't reach navigation controller in ViewController 1 to push other VC there. I tried to do it from window with code:

```
UITabBarController *mTabBarVC = (UITabBarController *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *prevNavigationController = myTabBarVC.selectedViewController.navigationController;
```

But I had no success I get nil in prevNavigationController.

Comment: what show NSLog (@"%@", mTabBarVC) ?

Comment: and NSLog (@"%@", myTabBarVC.selectedViewController) ?

Comment: check, if keyWindow.rootViewController really UITabBarController, not another controller

Comment: how you present ViewController 2 over ViewController 1? Modal, or by add subview?

Answer (score 0):

Create in ViewController 2.h:

```
@property UIViewController *parent;
```

In ViewController 1 pass self:

```
viewController2.parent = self;
```

In ViewController 2 you can now get UINavigationController:

```
UINavigationController *navVC = self.parent.navigationController;
```

It's the best way, because you can change structure of your view controllers in future and will get a bug.

If ViewController 2 present modally on ViewController 1, you can get VC1 from VC2 in `self.presentingViewController` property.